# Not sure why i can grab the html of an object but not the attribute

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

Currently i have it working just not in the way i wanted it to. I am currently grabbing the html of the current object and passing it through a switch statement.  I am wanting to grab the attribute or data name if possible which i am sure it is i just cant figure it out. I would of made a jsfiddle but i couldn't figure out how to do it with the foundation framework and the ajax call.
I appreciate any help given.

The problem is in the javascript under the function showMsg(). the variable is assigned to the var name 'k'. as you can see it is currently selecting the html of the event object. when i try using the attribute selector it returns an error of undefined.

Here is my jack.hmtl file which is being called using ajax

```
<section class="jack">
<ul>
    <li data-id="1" attr="1"><button class="button select" data-id="1" attr="1">Select me-1</button></li>
    <li data-id="2" attr="2"><button class="button select" data-id="2" attr="2">Select me-2</button></li>
    <li data-id="3" attr="3"><button class="button select" data-id="3" attr="3">Select me-3</button></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

My javascript file:

```
function borderAnimation(){
var cnt = $(".content"),
    body = $('body'),
    page = '',
    cntToggle = 'off';
cnt.hide();
var loadBoarder = {
    jack: function(){
        var that = $(this);
        that.css('background', 'red');
    },
    borderAni: function(){
        body.css({borderLeftWidth: "0px",
                      borderTopWidth: "0px",
                      borderRightWidth: "0px",
                      borderBottomWidth: "0px"
        });
        body.animate({borderLeftWidth: "6em",
                      borderTopWidth: "6em",
                      borderRightWidth: "6em",
                      borderBottomWidth: "6em"
        }, loadBoarder.displayBtn);
    },
    displayBtn: function(){
        $.ajax('jack.html', {
            url: 'jack.html',
            success: function(response){
                var ctr = $(".container");
                ctr.append(response);
                ctr.find("button").first().fadeOut();
                loadBoarder.eatJack();
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("ERROR WITH AJAX");
            }
        });//END OF AJAX CALL
    },
    closeButton: function(){
        cnt.animate({left: "-2000px"});
        cnt.fadeOut();
        $('.jack ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
    },                                                                              
    showMsg: function(){
        var k = $(this).html(),
            **//--- want to use $(this).attr(), ---\\**
            lop = $(this).parent().offset(),
            arrowPos = (lop.left),
            arrow = $(".arrow-up");
            console.log(k);
        loadBoarder.loadImages();
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            cnt.show();
            $(".jack").find('li').removeClass('active');
            var ani = function(){
                cntToggle = 'on';
                if(cnt.css('left') === '0px'){
                    cnt.animate({left: "-2000px"}, "easeout");
                    cnt.animate({left: '0'}, "easein");
                }
                else{
                    cnt.animate({left: '0'});
                }
            };
            var arrowAni = function(){
                arrow.hide();
                arrow.css({top: '20px', left: arrowPos+"px"});
                arrow.fadeIn();
                arrow.delay(200).animate({top: '-20px', left: arrowPos});
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            };
            var aniArrow = function(){
                arrow.css({top: '20px', left: arrowPos+"px"});
                arrow.css({top: '-20px', left: arrowPos+"px"});
            };
            switch(k) {
                case "Select me-1":
                $('.ss').hide();
                $('.one').show();
                page = 'one';
                    if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
                        aniArrow();
                        $('.jack');
                    }else{
                        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                        arrowAni();
                        ani();
                    }
                break;
                case "Select me-2":
                    $('.ss').hide();
                    $('.two').show();
                    page = 'two';
                    if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
                        aniArrow();
                        $('.jack');
                    }else{
                        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                        arrowAni();
                        ani();
                    }
                break;
                case "Select me-3":
                    $('.ss').hide();
                    $('.three').show();
                    page = 'three';
                    if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
                        aniArrow();
                        $('.jack');
                    }else{
                        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                        arrowAni();
                        ani();
                    }
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    eatJack: function(){
        console.log("REALY SLOW");
        var listItems = $('.jack ul').find('li'),
            item = listItems.find("button"),
            items = [];
        listItems.each(function(){
            items.push($(this));
            item.css({marginTop: "250px"});
            item.animate({marginTop: "0"}, "easeOutBounce");
        });
    },
    loadImages: function(){

    }
   };//END OF loadBorder OBJECT

     // EVENTS
     $('body').on('click', ".select", loadBoarder.showMsg);
     $('button').on('click', loadBoarder.borderAni);
     $('body').on('click', '.close', loadBoarder.closeButton);
}

   //WHEN DOCUMENT IS FINSHED LOADING EXECUTE THIS FUNCTION
   $(function() {
         borderAnimation();
   });
```

Comment: Please only include the shortest code necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I would just show that function alone but i figured it might help who over is looking at to fully understand what i am trying to do. sorry

Comment: What attribute are you trying to get? `attr()` requires a parameter specifying the attribute you are trying to get

Comment: $(this).attr('attr') works, but i see why it's confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the jquery function attr requires a parameter, secondly, attr is not an element attribute. I would change your list items and your buttons to use rel instead of attr (if that doesnt conflict with anything else) and then your js for that variable would be:

var k = $(this).attr('rel')